# Instrumentation running failed due to NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am running Android test cases in Eclipse. When I run them individually, they execute correctly; but when I run all of them together, I face the issue: "android test run failed. instrumentation run failed due to `java.lang.NullPointerException`." At times, it is fine and sometimes ends up in error.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Add the whole stacktrace and the relevant code please.

Comment: Without `code` and `LogCat` we can't help you.

Comment: @Sharath why do you make all those edits of long-forgotten questions?

Comment: May be it would be useful for them or they would delete the ques